# Php Timestamp showing negative values when month change

Tags: php, opencart

In Php Controller code 'date_added' is already there and i created 'date_sla' for current date. In my out put individually both are working fine but when i use to calculate the difference result is fine for within the month. when month changes it showing negative numbers like (3-1-2017) - (31-12-2016) = -28 days

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $action = array();

    $action[] = array(
                'text' => $this->language->get('text_view'),
                'href' => $this->url->link('sale/order/info', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&order_id=' . $result['order_id'] . $url, 'SSL')
            );

    if (strtotime($result['date_added']) > strtotime('-' . (int)$this->config->get('config_order_edit') . ' day')) {
        $action[] = array(
                    'text' => $this->language->get('text_edit'),
                    'href' => $this->url->link('sale/order/update', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&order_id=' . $result['order_id'] . $url, 'SSL')
                );
    }

    $this->data['orders'][] = array(
                'order_id'      => $result['order_id'],
                'customer'      => $result['customer'],
                'status'        => $result['status'],
                'total'         => $this->currency->format($result['total'], $result['currency_code'], $result['currency_value']),
                'date_added'    => date($this->language->get('date_format_short'), strtotime($result['date_added'])),
                'date_sla'    => date($this->language->get('date_format_short'), time()),
                'date_modified' => date($this->language->get('date_format_short'), strtotime($result['date_modified'])),
                'selected'      => isset($this->request->post['selected']) && in_array($result['order_id'], $this->request->post['selected']),
                'action'        => $action
            );
}
```

Html code

```
<td class="right"><?php echo $order['date_sla'] - $order['date_added']." days";?></td>
```

Comment: What part of you thought that doing a subtraction on 2 strings would ever be a good idea. You get 28 from that subtraction because `3 - 31` is `-28` When you do maths on strings it converts the string to a number until it finds a non numeric value (i.e. the first space or `-`) in the string hence `3 - 31`

Comment: I am also guessing that you stored the dates as TEXT or VARCHAR in your database. Start again and use DATETIME or TIMESTAMP data types for dates and times. Only convert to a string in the presentation layer when needed

Comment: I got your point. may be i created this $order['date_sla'] in wrong place. give me some time i will cross check it once again. And don't mind if any silly mistakes made by me. I am beginner in Php. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First echo the `$order['date_sla']` and `$order['date_added']` and  see what it prints, if your date is of the format as mention in your sentence (3-1-2017) then try like this:

```
$d1 = new DateTime('3-1-2017');
$d2 = new DateTime('31-12-2016');
$difference = $d2->diff($d1);
echo $difference->format('%r%a days');// 3 days
```

**EXAMPLE FOR YOUR DATE FORMAT FROM IMAGE:**

```
$t=explode("-",'03/01/2017 - 05:23:23 AM');//replace 03/01/2017 - 05:23:23 AM with your variable $order['date_sla'] like $t=explode("-",$order['date_sla']);
$str=str_replace("/", "-", $t[0]);
$t1=explode("-",'31/12/2016 - 05:23:23 AM');//replace 03/01/2017 - 05:23:23 AM with your variable $order['date_added' like $t=explode("-",$order['date_added');
$str1=str_replace("/", "-",$t1[0]);

$d1 = new DateTime($str);
$d2 = new DateTime($str1);
$difference = $d2->diff($d1);
echo $difference->format('%r%a days');// 3 days
```

Comment: <?php $order['date_sla']." days";?>
<?php $order['date_added']." days";?> Both are showing fine results

Comment: @ImmranMohammed you should post the output.I'm guessing you are having `numbers` not `date/datetime` string in that case if you subtract `3-31` in is obvious to get `-28`. you need to get the full `date` or `datetime` value from `db` the process the way i have written.

Comment: added a screenshot

Comment: @ImmranMohammed what is the second marked field get the date from that and next to that and create datetime object from that string and do the subtraction.

Comment: Forget about second field (date modified), I want to calculate the difference between date added and current date. Thank you very much for your interest.

Comment: Can i Use like this ..     $d1 = new DateTime('$order['date_sla']');
$d2 = new DateTime('$order['date_added']');
$difference = $d2->diff($d1);
echo $difference->format('%r%a days');

Comment: This code is working with pre defined days and how can i add my variable s in this code. can you please explain that will more helpful for me.

Comment: @ImmranMohammed i have added an example for your case, Try that.

Comment: Wow, Its works like miracle, May i know what is the mistake i made and how this code works. May be this will use full for our future readers.

Comment: Thanks alot Mr.Suchit

Comment: @ImmranMohammed `DateTIme`does not support `'03/01/2017'` structure of date so first we need to convert it in a proper structure which `DateTIme ` then we can proceed further. Glad it worked for you.

Comment: @ImmranMohammed `$d1 = new DateTime('$order['date_sla']');` is wrong you should use it like: `$d1 = new DateTime($order['date_sla']);`.

Comment: I got it. I have to change the date structure in my database settings. Otherwise replace in code as you did.  $str=str_replace("/", "-", $t[0]); Thanks again for explanation.